# How do you parse out data from a dataframe for each ID when an adjacent column contains a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a large dataframe in the following format. I need to parse out only the values where values ==1 and through the remaining id. This should reset on each ID so that it takes the first value in a unique id that contains the value 1 and ends when the id number terminates.

```
d={'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5] \
        ,'values':[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,] }
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df



ND = {'ID':[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5],\
 'values':[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]}

    
df_final=pd.DataFrame(ND)
df_final
```

'''

Comment: Could you extend the explanation about the logic behind the selection please? For example in ID==2, how it pass from `1 0 1 1 1`  to `1 1 1 0 0`?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo

Comment: ND = {'ID':[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5],\
     'values':[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]}

df_final=pd.DataFrame(ND)
df_final

Comment: I am trying to figure out a formula for a problem which shares this format. I have multiple patient ID's and once they receive a letter I need to report what the action was when they responded. In this case the '1' will indicate that the letter was received and the 0's indicate no response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df[df.groupby('ID')['values'].transform('cummax')==1]
```

Output:

```
    ID  values
3    1       1
4    1       0
5    2       1
6    2       0
7    2       1
8    2       1
9    2       1
11   3       1
12   3       0
13   3       0
18   4       1
19   4       1
20   4       0
21   4       1
22   4       0
23   5       1
24   5       1
25   5       1
26   5       1
27   5       1
```

Details, use cummax to keep the value of 1 after first found. Then use equal to 1 to create a boolean series, which then is used to do boolean indexing.

Comment: yes once again I got second because I added to many words before posting the answer haha

Comment: @Ben.T Keep your answer.  You did a better job of explanation.  :)    Next time.  solution then explain. hahaha!

Answer (score 3):

if your column values is only 0 and 1, you can use `groupby.cummax` that will replace 0 by 1 if they are after a 1 per ID, then use this as a boolean mask:

```
df_ = df[df.groupby('ID')['values'].cummax().astype(bool).to_numpy()]
print(df_)
    ID  values
3    1       1
4    1       0
5    2       1
6    2       0
7    2       1
8    2       1
9    2       1
11   3       1
12   3       0
13   3       0
18   4       1
19   4       1
20   4       0
21   4       1
22   4       0
23   5       1
24   5       1
25   5       1
26   5       1
27   5       1
```

Comment: Gotcha by 5 seconds?  Although you did add explanation. +1